# DirectShow webcam video and audio async - audio lag

Tags: c#, video, webcam, directshow, directshow.net

I try to save a video with audio and save it as an uncompressed avi file. The graph is as you can see in the picture. The problem is that the sound recording is ~500ms behind the video. It doesn't matter which sources I have. What can I do to have video and audio in sync?

[image]

Comment: You can try to play with AVI Mux filter's properties, namely the IConfigInterleaving::put_Interleaving. You can test it first in graph builder through the AVI Mux property page, to see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Default audio capture buffer is pretty large and is about 500 ms in length. You start getting the data once the buffer is filled and hence the lag. Large buffers might be okay for some scenarios and are not good for other. You can use `IAMBufferNegotiation` interface to adjust the buffering.

See related (you will see 500 ms lag is a typical complaint):

- [Audio Sync problems using DirectShow.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10235794/868014)
- [Minimizing audio capture latency in DirectShow](https://sid6581.wordpress.com/2006/10/09/minimizing-audio-capture-latency-in-directshow/)
- [Delay in video in DirectShow graph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26669175/868014)